# Passing uniqueidentifier parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to pass a uniqueidentifier parameter to a stored procedure using the following code:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@BlogID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = "96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04";
```

I keep getting an error however saying that the program was unable to convert from string to GUID. Am I passing the value incorrectly?

Comment: are you setting `Value` to a  string representation or a guid?

Comment: it's a string, but it is in the GUID format

Comment: You say "I give you a Guid!", but you give it a string. No wonder the poor one is confused. Give it a Guid!

Comment: There is a constructor for the Guid structure which accepts a string parameter (to convert the string representation of a GUID into a new Guid object). See also [Guid(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor#System_Guid__ctor_System_String_) Another alternative is to use [Guid.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parse#System_Guid_Parse_System_String_) and similar methods.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@BlogID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid("96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04");
```

Comment: Downvote because it is missing an explanation. Please explain what is wrong, instead of just saying "Do this."

Comment: For VB, with "Option Strict On", the line would look like this `paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@blogID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) With {.Value = New Guid("96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04")})`

Answer (score 8):

A unique identifier is a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx). so it's a different object type to your string.

You need

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@BlogID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = 
                                        new Guid("96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04");
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you are not comparing the uniqueidentifier to any string in the database.

When I ran into this, I found a section where I had the following line:

IF @MyGuid IS NULL OR @MyGuid = ''
BEGIN...

The { @MyGuid = '' } part will cause the error you described.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31846178)