# Scope_Identity not working with GUID on c#

Tags: c#, database, insert, scope, guid

I've been trying to insert some data on a database and at the same time get the identifier.

The identifier type is a Guid.

I already tried some resolutions.

I was searching but I couldn't found any that worked with a Guid in C#.

The last one I tried was like this:

```
        dbAccess db = new dbAccess();
        SqlConnection con = db.openConnection();
        Guid retVal = Guid.Empty;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into Comment(IdDiscussion,UserId,Description,DateTime)
                                            values(@IdDiscussion,@UserId,@description,@dateTime);
                                            set @ret=SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdDiscussion", discussionId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", comment);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTime", dateTime);
            SqlParameter retParameter = new SqlParameter("@ret", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
            retParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(retParameter);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            retVal = (Guid)retParameter.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //doesn't really matter
        }
        db.closeConnection();
        return retVal;
```

In this case I get the following error on `executeNonQuery(): "Operand type clash: numeric is incompatible with uniqueidentifier"`.

Any suggestion that can help?

Comment: If, all that you want is to pass unique identifier to the database, did you try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724614/passing-uniqueidentifier-parameter-to-stored-procedure ?

Comment: I want to get the unique identifier of the inserted row.

Comment: Appending: ";SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();" to end of the in line query and calling ExecuteScalar(...) might do the trick for you. Also, please take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913115/scope-identity-in-c-sharp-range

Comment: Is your Identity Column in `Comment` Table of type `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: I already tryed the executescalar with the select scope at the end but it didn't work either.Yes, my column identity type os uniqueidentifier.

Comment: The problem is, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the result of the last incremented Indentity column in your scope, this is always an number, as all identity columns are numeric. Your `uniquieidentifier` column is not an indentity column so has nothing to do with the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function.

Answer (score 3):

scope_identity() only returns the last (scoped) identity value - this value datatype has to be numeric.

So unfortunetly only fix that comes to my mind would be something like this:

```
declare @op table
(
    ColGuid uniqueidentifier
)

insert into Comment(IdDiscussion,UserId,Description,DateTime)
output inserted.CommentId -- GUID column
into @op
values (@IdDiscussion,@UserId,@description,@dateTime)

select top 1 o.ColGuid
from @op o
```

and then in your code:

```
var guid = (Guid)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

One more mention: this solution should work in SQL Server 2005 and above

Comment: or a more simple version:
`var sql = "insert into yourTable(col2,col3) output inserted.guidCol values('test','best')";
    var guid = (Guid) cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve Guid values, but not worked with me. You can try declare a SQL variable and generate a new guid with the command NEWID() and in the end do a SELECT command in this variable executing ExecuteScalar method on the command object.

```
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER; SET @Id = NEWID();
INSERT INTO [tablename] ([Id], [Field1], [Field2]) VALUES (@Id, @Field1, @Field2);
```

You must add your parameters on the command normally.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", "Field 1 Value");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field2", "Field 2 Value"));
```

So, execute and retrieve the value.

```
var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Guid guid = (Guid)obj;
```