# Conversion failed when converting from string to uniqueidentifier - loading DataTable with ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In attempting to do a SQL query (which returns one string and one uniqueidentifier to columns 0 and 1 respectively) I get "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier" in my exceptions log. How can I avoid this? I'm assuming the issue is, the datatables columns are not defined, so it's expecting a string and SQL is trying to convert it. The exception is logged. Surprisingly to me the GUID is stored successfully to da[1]. So my program technically works, however I want to clear this exception and to do that I need to understand why it's happening and how to go about fixing it.

```
da = new DataTable();
da.Clear();
...
string invoiceStatusSQL = @"select status,invoice_id from invoices where acct_id='" + accountid + "'";
command = new SqlCommand(invoiceStatusSQL, cnn);
da.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: **Always use parameterized sql and avoid string concatenation** to add values to sql statements. This mitigates SQL Injection vulnerabilities and ensures values are passed to the statement correctly. See [How can I add user-supplied input to an SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35163361/1260204), and [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: What is `accountid`?  Is it `Guid`?  You should always parameterise your SQL queries

Comment: Maybe see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436001/3744182) to [C# guid and SQL uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1435908/3744182) and also [Passing uniqueidentifier parameter to Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11724614/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always parameterise your SQL queries to help prevent SQL injection *and* avoid problems like you're facing now. See [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Use [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8) to add the parameters to the SqlCommand.

```
string invoiceStatusSQL = @"select status, invoice_id from invoices where acct_id = @accountId";
command = new SqlCommand(invoiceStatusSQL, cnn);

SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@accountId", accountid);
command.Parameters.Add(idParam);

da.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
```

---

You can also specify the actual database type when creating the parameter, which will reduce any [issues](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) you might have with the framework inferring the type incorrectly (although I don't think that would happen in your case for a Guid/UniqueIdentifier).  One way to specify the type is shown below.

```
var p = new SqlParameter 
            { 
                ParameterName = "@accountId", 
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,  
                Value = accountid  
            };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer with examples. This solved the issue. I've read up on it quit a bit in the past hour and you've all taught me a few things. Much appreciated.

Comment: The .Add method has an overload that accepts the `SqlDbType` and another that will accept the type and field size. `command.Parameters.Add("@accountId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentiifer).Value = accountid`